# How to filter with month and year in django

Tags: django

I have a form to filter students by joined year and month. This code is working fine if I filter by year but it is not working if I filter by month. How can i solve this?
It displays no data available for the month.

> models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    joined_date = models.DateField()
```

> views.py

```
def serachstudent(request):
    q = request.GET["q"]
    if q:
        students = Student.objects.filter(Q(joined_date__year__icontains=q)|Q(joined_date__month__icontains=q))
        return render(request, "students/view_students.html", {'students': students})
    else:
        return redirect('students:view_student')
```

> template

```
<form action="{% url 'students:search_student' %}" class='form-inline'>
          <!--<label for="month"></label>-->
          <select name="q">
            <option disabled selected>Select Year</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
             <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2019">2019</option>
          </select>
          <!--<label for="month"></label>-->
          <select name="q">
            <option disabled selected>Select month</option>
            <option value="01">January</option>
            <option value="02">February</option>
             <option value="03">March</option>
            <option value="04">April</option>
            <option value="05">May</option>
            <option value="06">June</option>
             <option value="07">July</option>
            <option value="08">August</option>
             <option value="09">September</option>
            <option value="10">Octbor</option>
             <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12">Decembery</option>

          </select>

     &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" >Find Students</button>
                    </div>

      </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this

```
students = Student.objects.filter(Q(joined_date__year=q)|Q(joined_date__month=q))
```

Comment: thak you it worked.What if i have to use and method

Comment: filter(joined_date__year=year, joined_date__month=month)